# I have created a laser that takes 2 hit to kill the type 2 asteroid and 1 hit to kill the type 1. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: lua

So I have been making adjustments to an sdk game called "Star Explorer" in lua. I came across this idea about having 2 types of asteroids, 1 which will take 2 hits by the laser to actually die. I did not have any errors while creating the asteroid that takes up 2 hits to die. Although it still does not take 2 shots top die.

Code:

```
local function onCollision( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        local obj1 = event.object1
        local obj2 = event.object2

        if ( ( obj1.myName == "laser" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" ) or
             ( obj1.myName == "asteroid" and obj2.myName == "laser" ) or
       ( obj1.myName == "lasers" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" )  )
        then
            -- Remove both the laser and asteroid
            display.remove( obj2 )

            -- Play explosion sound!
            audio.play( explosionSound )

            for i = #asteroidsTable, 1, -1 do
                if ( asteroidsTable[i] == obj1 or asteroidsTable[i] == obj2 ) then
                    table.remove( asteroidsTable, i )
                    break
                end
            end

            -- Increase score
            score = score + 100
            scoreText.text = "Score: " .. score

        elseif ( ( obj1.myName == "ship" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" ) or
                 ( obj1.myName == "asteroid" and obj2.myName == "ship" ) )
        then
            if ( died == false ) then
                died = true

                -- Play explosion sound!
                audio.play( explosionSound )

                -- Update lives
                lives = lives - 1
                livesText.text = "Lives: " .. lives

                if ( lives == 0 ) then
                    display.remove( ship )  

          display.remove(emitter)
                    timer.performWithDelay( 2000, endGame )
                else
                    ship.alpha = 0
          emitter.alpha = 0
          timer.performWithDelay( 2000, restoreShip )
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

local function onCollision( event )

        if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

            local obj1 = event.object1
            local obj2 = event.object2

            if ( ( obj1.myName == "laser" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" ) or
                 ( obj1.myName == "asteroid" and obj2.myName == "laser" ) or
           ( obj1.myName == "lasers" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" )  )
            then
                -- Remove both the laser and asteroid
                display.remove( obj2 )

                -- Play explosion sound!
                audio.play( explosionSound )

                for i = #asteroidsTable, 1, -1 do
                    if ( asteroidsTable[i] == obj1 or asteroidsTable[i] == obj2 ) then
                        table.remove( asteroidsTable, i )
                        break
                    end
                end

                -- Increase score
                score = score + 200
                scoreText.text = "Score: " .. score

            elseif ( ( obj1.myName == "ship2" and obj2.myName == "asteroid" ) or
                     ( obj1.myName == "asteroid" and obj2.myName == "ship2" ) )
            then
                if ( died == false ) then
                    died = true

                    -- Play explosion sound!
                    audio.play( explosionSound )

                    -- Update lives
                    lives = lives - 4
                    livesText.text = "Lives: " .. lives

                    if ( lives == 0 ) then
                        display.remove( ship2 )  

              display.remove(emitter)
                        timer.performWithDelay( 2000, endGame )
                    else
                        ship2.alpha = 0
              emitter.alpha = 0
              timer.performWithDelay( 2000, restoreShip )
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: why do you have two functions with the same name? is the first one obsolete?

Comment: `display.remove( obj2 )` but maybe asteroid is an `obj1` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to format your question to explain *exactly what* your problem is, and to give context to relevant pieces of code (Trying to read a big block of code is hard work for anyone answering your question). As such, I really can't help you improve *your* code, but I can explain how you might accomplish the goal you want.

First of all, in each object in your `asteroids` dictionary, include a variable called `lives`. Upon a collision with a laser, reduce `lives` by `1`, and only destroy the asteroid if `lives` becomes `0`. It appears from my brief glance at your code that you are destroying the asteroid no matter what. Also, it seems like you have two identical functions with the same name, and you are removing `obj2` without determining if it is an asteroid or laser? I'd put a conditional at the top to assign some variable, say `laser`, to whichever object *is* the laser, and `asteroid` to the asteroid object.